# Should I not use css frameworks for portfolio site (full stack developer)

Tags: portfolio

I have heard people suggest not to use frameworks like bootstrap or materialize when making a portfolio site. However, many of those people are front end developers or people more skilled in design than I am.

I am a full stack developer and do a lot of backend work (though I have done front end and responsive work but usually with a team, or with a framework) so I'm not the greatest designer. Would it be okay to use css frameworks, or would employers look down upon this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a web development stack exchange site

Comment: I would disagree as this is more catered towards employment, there is plenty of portfolio questions asked on the workplace stack, but the webmaster and web app stack exchange is more for technical questions

Comment: quite some are closed, career advice are off-topic. If you think you need a framework then go for it. Otherwise if you have designer in your enterprise, maybe you should try to get some help from them ? I'm fullstack too, more specialized in backend, if someone complain about using basic bootstrap design, I would answer that I am no designer.

Answer (score 3):

Employers are not going to spend any of their time investigating the CSS framework you use. You should spend your time worrying about more significant things.

The advice to not use a framework is rubbish anyway. No one would ever hire a developer who insists on writing everything from "the ground up." Unless you are in the business of developing frameworks.

Comment: I did have seen a project in Java (web project) were the usage of any framework was forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your portfolio should represent the skills and technologies you mention in your application. If you apply for using the frameworks you mentioned, use these.